# Using dynamic filters to aggregate data in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, aggregate

I have data in this format:

```
Category Subcategory   User   Count1    Count2
  A           a        New     3000      2000
  A           a        Old      300       200
  A           b        New     4000      3000
  A           b        Old      400       300
  B           c        New     4000      3000
  B           c        Old      600       400
```

I have coded 3 filters for Category, Subcategory and User and an output data table in this way:

```
    selectInput('cat', 'Category', choices = c('All', category)),
    selectInput('sub', 'Subcategory', choices = c('All', subcategory)),
    selectInput('user', 'User', c('All', 'New', 'Old')),
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
```

`category` and `subcategory` in the choices argument are lists. I can filter the data in this way with user inputs :

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(input$cat == 'All'){data <- data}
    else{data <- data[data$Category == input$cat, ]}
    if(input$user == 'All'){data <- data}
    else{data <- data[data$User== input$user, ]}
    if(input$sub == 'All'){data <- data}
    else{data<- data[data$Subcategory == input$sub, ]}
})
```

The problem I have is that I need to aggregate the **count** columns when 'All' argument is input by the user. For example if user inputs 'All' for Subcategory and User and 'A' for Category, the output data table should look like:

```
Category Subcategory   User   Count1    Count2
  A           All      All     7700      5500
```

**or**

```
Category  Count1    Count2
  A        7700      5500
```

I can write if-else conditions for this but in the actual data there are 6-8 filters and I wonder if there is any easier way to aggregate the data without writing if-else controls for all the combinations of aggregations (like aggregate on **New** users on **All** Categories and Subcategories **or** aggregate on **All** Categories, Subcategories and Users etc.).

Comment: I think I have found a solution, will post after confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this inside `DT::renderDataTable`:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
idx <- which(c(input$cat, input$user, input$sub) != "All")
myvars <- colnames(data)[1:3][idx]

data %>%
  {`if`(input$cat ==  "All", . , filter(., Category == input$cat))} %>% 
  {`if`(input$user == "All", . , filter(., User == input$user))} %>%
  {`if`(input$sub ==  "All", . , filter(., Subcategory == input$sub))} %>%
  {`if`(length(myvars) == 0, ., group_by_at(., myvars) %>% 
          summarise_at(vars(matches("^Count")), sum))}
})
```

Short explanation:

`summarise` is the `dplyr` equivalent of `aggregate`. `summarise_at` is a special case of `summarise`: in the first argument you describe all the variables that you want to aggregate (or summarise). I put `matches("^Count")` which means that all variables that start with `"Count"` should be summarised. The second argument is the aggregating function `sum`.

Comment: Can you explain what happens here, I am not well versed with dplyr...
```summarise_at(vars(matches("^Count")), sum)```

Answer (score 0):

I added  **" "**  as the default value for the filters...

```
    selectInput('cat', 'Category', choices = c('','All', category)),
    selectInput('sub', 'Subcategory', choices = c('','All', subcategory)),
    selectInput('user', 'User', c('','All', 'New', 'Old')),
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
```

...and changed the column values based on the UI input.

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
 if(input$cat == '' | input$sub == '' | input$user == ''){return(NULL)}
 else{
    if(input$cat == 'All'){data$Category <- 'All'}
    else{data <- data[data$Category == input$cat, ]}
    if(input$user == 'All'){data$User <- 'All'}
    else{data <- data[data$User== input$user, ]}
    if(input$sub == 'All'){data$Subcategory <- 'All'}
    else{data<- data[data$Subcategory == input$sub, ]}
     }
 aggregate.data = aggregate(.~Category+Subcategory+User, data, sum)
})
```

In this way if User and Subcategory inputs are 'All' and Category column is 'A', the data first get filtered for all rows containing 'A' and 'All' and 'All' and then the resulting data set is aggregated over these three columns.